# How to make dialog components reusable in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-dialog

Can a dialog be altered to make its components reusable without having to type duplicate lines of code for multiple items. My list has more than one item. When I click the first list item (Starters), I want **Starters** as the dialog title and the `Screen.Starters.route` navigation route to be used, whereas when I click the other list item (Desserts), I want **Desserts** as the dialog title `Screen.Starters.route` navigation route to be used.

```
enum class Items(@StringRes val textResId: Int) {
    Starters(R.string.starters),
    Desserts(R.string.desserts)
}    

@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavController, dialogTitle: String) {
val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val dialogTitle: String
if (openDialog.value) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = {
            openDialog.value = false
        },
        title = {Text(dialogTitle)},
        text = {Text("Ready to order?")},
        confirmButton = {
            Button(onClick = {navController.navigate(route = Screen.Starters.route), openDialog.value = false}) {Text("Order food")}
        },
        dismissButton = {
            OutlinedButton(onClick = {openDialog.value = false}) {Text("Cancel")}
        }
    )
}

val myListener: (Items) -> Unit = { item ->
    when (item) {
        Items.Starters -> { openDialog.value = true }
        Items.Desserts -> { openDialog.value = true }
    }
}


Scaffold(
    topBar = {...},
    content = { it ->
        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.padding(it),
          lazyItems = arrayOf(Items.ItemStaters, Items.ItemDesserts),
          onClickItem = myListener) {
          Text(text = stringResource(id = it.textResId))
        }
    },
    containerColor = ...val
)
```

**Update**

```
    val myListener: (Items) -> Unit = { item ->
        when (item) {
            Items.Starters -> {
                MyDialog(
                    onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ },
                    title = { /*TODO*/ },
                    text = { /*TODO*/ },
                    dismissButton = { /*TODO*/ },
                    onConfirm = { /*TODO*/ }
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jetpack Compose you can make anything reusable using slot api as default Compososables do.

```
@Composable
fun MyDialog(
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit,
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    text: @Composable () -> Unit,
    dismissButton: @Composable () -> Unit,
    onConfirm: (String)->Unit
) {
    AlertDialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismissRequest,
        title =title,
        text = text,
        dismissButton = dismissButton,
        confirmButton = {
            Button(onClick = { 
                onConfirm("You picked....")
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Using this pattern which lets you pass your own Composables or lambdas you can customize your Dialog or Composable as you see fit and make it highly reusable.

If you wish to open such a dialog on a click from an Item with desired parameters you can add callback to items and set a state with correct value.

To open a dialog based on your Item and navigation i would change from a binary:

```
val openDialog = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
```

to class that contains item details such as

```
// This is your data class, it's a simplification for demonstration

data class Dessert(val id: Int)

@Composable
private fun MyDessertRow(
    dessert: Dessert, onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    // Some Row, Column, Etc
}

sealed class DialogOption {
    object None : DialogOption()
    class NewDialog(val item: Dessert) : DialogOption()
}
```

And add it as:

```
val desserts = listOf(Dessert(1), Dessert(2))

var showDialogOption:DialogOption by remember {
    mutableStateOf(DialogOption.None)
}
LazyColumn() {
    items(desserts) { dessert ->
        MyDessertRow(dessert = dessert,
            onClick = {
                showDialogOption = DialogOption.NewDialog(dessert)
            }
        )
    }
}

if (showDialogOption != DialogOption.None) {

    val options = showDialogOption as DialogOption.NewDialog

    val dessert = options.item
    MyDialog(
        onDismissRequest = { /*TODO*/ },
        title = { /*TODO*/ },
        text = { /*TODO*/ },
        dismissButton = { /*TODO*/ },
        onConfirm = {
                // Navigation here
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Great (see my **Update** code), and what is the correct way to call that dialog? The latest code will cause the `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function` error

Comment: @wbk727 have you checked updated answer?

Comment: Great but bear in mind that not all items in my LazyColumn will open a dialog when clicked.

Comment: you can set any property of  your items null like navigation id for instance, or even `onClick ` nullable for some items and make ` showDialogOption = DialogOption.NewDialog(dessert)` conditional for your items.

Comment: Where would I specify different values for the properties of `MyDialog` when different list items are clicked?

Comment: `MyDialog` is just a simple template. You can customize it as needed. For instance you always have the same layout for Text, instead of having `  text: @Composable () -> Unit` parameter have a `text:String`, also if you always have an image `imageBitmap: ImageBitmap`, etc. You should design `MyDialog` how your general properties will be. I put it as an example so you can see that you can have a Composable with value or Composable parameters. For instance you might not need dismiss button for some items create it as ` dismissButton: @Composable () -> Unit={}` which adds no button.

Comment: Interesting. Please provide the correct way to show text in each list item.

Comment: I don't know how your data classes work, so i posed a generic answer. The reason `listener` approach doesn't work is because you can't call a Composable from scope that doesn't have `@Composable` annotation. So you need to add clickable with a state that needs to trigger recomposition. and with new State value you can open a Dialog selectively. Which is done by a Boolean flag by defalut. Since yo want more customized Dialog you need to have more stateful value that' why `DialogOption ` is needed.

Comment: I'm able to continue in chat, `text:String` is not correct.

Comment: Now you are able to open dialog via click, now you need to do it selectively for your `Items `. In `onClick` of `MyDessertRow ` provided you can check which type of dessert it is and which action you want to take. If it's an item you want to show dialog you set ` showDialogOption = DialogOption.NewDialog(dessert)` and pass required info for dialog such as dessert title, image, navigation string, if you want to open one. Now you are able to trigger a recomposition that can open a Dialog

Comment: `showDialogOption` has an error and changing it to `var` will still give a different error. `Val cannot be reassigned`

Comment: What's the error you get? In my answer it's as `var showDialogOption:DialogOption by remember {
    mutableStateOf(DialogOption.None)`. It needs to be `var` to be mutable

Comment: The error is `Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'setValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>, DialogOption)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate for var (read-write property)`. I can also show any part of my code in the chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246129/discussion-between-thracian-and-wbk727).